# How to structure multi-user database software to be used over a LAN?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have developed a desktop-based book-keeping software for lawyers in C#. I have used SQLite for the database. The software is very well received by the small community of users who have installed it.

I would like to extend the functionality of this software to enable multiple installs over LAN.

The software would be capable of accessing the single common database over LAN and every one should be able to modify it.

I am not an expert with this. What points do I need to consider? Are there any examples available already?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good sample that demonstrates storing users in sql server, and it also steps you through creating the database:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

It is a web-based application, so you would need to convert the client side into windows forms.  If you need any help with that or anything else, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can Install MYSQL or MS-SQL on your server and put the credentials in your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not an expert at this, but if you could point to me  the things to consider like multiple read/write/ and access control, that would be wonderful

Comment: Do you want the client side to be a web application or Windows forms?

Comment: Its WinForm right now. I would prefer a Windows Forms over LAN as well